# Command not executing in row level ContextMenu on DataGrid in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have my template declared like so -

```
<DataGrid.Resources>

    <ContextMenu x:Key="RowMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding Cancel}" />
    </ContextMenu>

</DataGrid.Resources>
```

I'm applying the template using row style -

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
    </Style>

</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The menu shows up ok

But the command (on the ItemListViewModel) does not execute when a context menu item is clicked

```
public class ItemListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void Cancel()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cancel test");
    }
...
}
```

My binding is otherwise working properly, as I can do things like this -

```
    foreach (ItemListViewModel ul in mylist.SelectedItems)
        MessageBox.Show(item.FullDescription);
```

I've been at this all night trying to figure it out. Just started with WPF today.

Please somebody tell me where I've gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can bind to a simple method. You need to bind to a command that should be an implementation of `ICommand` interface. In you case you need to create a class that would implement that interface and add property of that class type to your model.

See this example as a reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: But I do other bindings this way, what's different?

Answer (score 0):

I decided ListView was better for my needs and I'm using that instead. I'm no longer trying to bind the context menu to the item, but rather have a single context menu for the whole listview and simply enable or disable items in the ContextMenuOpen event where need be.